# Easily Cropping a Video

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I recorded a video at 1080x1920px resolution, and wanted to crop this video, by removing a little bit from the top and a lot from the bottom.

I went about it by -

1. Importing the video (drag and drop)
2. The video was being squished, I managed to fix this by Right clicking on the video -> Movie Strip -> Set Render Size.
3. I calculated exactly how many pixels I wanted to crop from the top by clicking on the preview and noting down the readings on the Y axis.
4. I then did some basic math and converted the Y axis readings to the appropriate offsets and used the Adjust -> Crop to enter these offsets.
5. I then changed the Render dimensions by calculating the difference between the original height and the sum of the offsets.
6. Ensured the height is divisible by 2.

This was quite cumbersome. Is there an easier way to do this in Blender? Ideally I would love it if I could just drag a box over the desired area and Blender does all these calculations for me.

Comment: It's best to use e.g. free online video editors.

Answer (score 1):

Grap the Transform Tools add-on: https://github.com/tin2tin/VSE_Transform_Tools

[image]